# Saving elements of a collection in a database only if they don't exist

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, persistence

I have a collection of objects (id-type1-type2) which I must save in the database if they don't exist already.

The type1-type2 combinations must be UNIQUE in the database (there's a unique constraint in the database for this combination). My question is: how do I persist the data in my collection (can be thousands of objects) without getting a SQL exception (due to the unique constraint) without checking if each record in the collection exists in the DB before persisting it? Is this even possible?

Do I have to iterate the collection, check the existence of each record (one database call for each check) and then saveAll those that do not exist there?
Is there a better way to minimize the round-trips? Maybe I can get all records, filter them with my collection (those that exist in both collection) and then persist only the new ones. In this case, I make 2 db calls. However, I'm worried about memory in this case.

I'm using Java and Spring but this is a general question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be thorough. If you are using UniqueKeyConstraint with the key combination (Field1-Field2), the database itself will do the job for you.

Comment: Yes, I am using the UniqueKeyConstraint for the database. However, it doesn''t seem like the database does that work for me. I mean, it prevents records with repeated combinations to be added but an exception is thrown. I want to persist records without an exception

Comment: Make sure your table is empty before you apply the UniqueKeyConstraint.
Adding it later(i.e., when you already have rows in your table) will make no effect.